# Meaning of this pointer type-casting notation

Tags: c++, c, pointers, types, casting

I have seen this type of declaration many times and have no idea what it's doing:

```
*(type*)$var
```

for example:

```
*(char *)&myChar
```

If the address of `myChar` is being retrieved and it is casted to `char` pointer then why the extra pointer outside and why is the address which is possibly an int or hex value being casted as a pointer? This makes no sense to me. I am a beginner so please, step by step explain what is going on here and why use this confusing format for type casting. Thank you.

Comment: `*(type*)$var` is not valid C syntax.

Comment: If you know that type of `myChar`, it would be helpful to explain what the intent of that construct is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
*(char *)&myChar
```

Address of `myChar` is taken, then *casted* to `char*`, and finally the object pointed by it is accessed. The effect is that, the access will according to the *casted* pointer type. For example

```
int x;
char c = *(char*)&x;
```

Here `x` is of type `int`, but it is being accessed as `char`. In effect **1 Byte**, since `char`  size is 1 byte.

This type of casting is useful in cases like you *pack* several data of smaller size in a larger size. In the above case, you can store 4 characters (assuming int has size  4 Byte) in a single integer, and then access them individually. But in C++ code they are rarely used.

Comment: ahhhh so that last * is for dereferencing thank you sir.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1 by definition.

Answer (score 2):

`*(type *)&var` is a common C idiom for reinterpreting the bits of a value as a different type.

For example, you may sometimes see

```
char buf[4];
*(uint32_t *)&buf = 32;
```

which writes the bit representation of 32 to the array `buf`.

*Note*: This idiom is not always safe, and is essentially non-portable. It may also break terribly if the value under consideration is not aligned correctly. Most uses are also subject to the platform's endianness. Use with extreme caution!